# Do I need to pay taxes in Italy if I'm inheriting in France?

Tags: france, taxes, italy

I am inheriting 100k€ in my home country, France. The account is a french one.
However, I am currently residing in Italy :I got an Italian ID card, work, pay my taxes and live there 99% of the year. I am not an italian citizen, and my status is the one of a student.

Do I need to pay taxes on this money?

Comment: If you are inheriting in France, there probably is a _notaire_ involved. Did you ask them about your question ?

Comment: The notaire is asking me this question. I think she is not used to this type of situation (in particular, I cannot go back to France right now)

Comment: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2012:201:0107:0134:FR:PDF